# Wrap Chained Calls in Kotlin Dilemma

Tags: android, kotlin

What's the recommended convention for [wrap chained call](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#wrap-chained-calls) if my previous line ended with a single closing bracket?

Am I supposed to keep it "disconnected" as below?

```kotlin
val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
    InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext,
    MyDatabase::class.java,
    testDatabase,
)
    .addMigrations(*manualMigrations)
    .addMigrations(*manualMigrations)
    .build()
```

Comment: I don't think there is a recommendation, some style guides / auto-formatters might have an opinion though. Personally though, that looks weird to me, it doesn't "underhang" like the normal chained call convention. I usually append the call to the ``)`` or ``}`` if it's on a line on its own, so ``).addMigrations``. Even though there isn't an explicit recommendation, I feel like that's similar to the convention for Class Headers (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#class-headers) where the superclass / interface stuff follows on the same line

Comment: You can always choose not to wrap, if that looks nicer to you. The convention just says "when you wrap, you should do like this". It doesn't say you always have to wrap.

Comment: I have enhanced the question with two migration rows to make it more prominent. 

in such situation, would go with the approach above? the problem is, if I stick the first line with the bracket, the code formatter will not align the 2nd addMigrations with the first one.

Comment: You could add an extra indent to lines 2-5. This question is off-topic because it is opinion-based.